# Cannot install MySQL 8 in the Ubuntu container

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, containers

I would like to install Mysql in my Ubuntu container. The reason is my app inside the container needs mysql command to run `mysql -u root -p -h "mysql server IP address"`. But I received this error:

```
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
mysqld: [ERROR] Stopped processing the 'includedir' directive in file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 20.
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to run `chmod 777 -R /etc/mysql` but it still doesn't work.

How do I install mysql-server in the Ubuntu container?

I am very new to MySQL, any help is appreciated!

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: There's quite a few other answers that indicate that you should keep your application and database containers separate. One function per container. Use compose files to show the orchestration of your application stack.